# ./gradlew assembleRelease doesn't give me a signed apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I'm seeing an instance where `./gradlew assembleRelease` is not actually outputting a signed apk. The build finishes with no errors (at least as far as I can tell).

I tested to see if the credentials portion isn't working, but when providing no credentials or incorrect credentials (as a test to see if the signing portion fails silently), the build obviously fails (red letters - `BUILD FAILED`).

At the end of the `./gradlew assembleRelease` I end up with unsigned builds in my outputs/apk dir. I've tried doing a `./gradlew clean` and re-running. I verified that this directory gets removed and recreated.

Any recommendations to help troubleshoot this?

Comment: You have the signing key stuff set up properly in the build script, I take it? Can we see?

Comment: Pretty sure I found my problem. Tried to get fancy with renaming the apk and messed up file paths, I believe.

Comment: @loeschg how did you fix it? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @Olayinka see the answer below. I self-answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had some hackery (-_-) going on to rename the apk (`variant.outputs.each //...`) which caused the problems.

Used the following instead

```
    project.ext.set('archivesBaseName', 'appname-' + versionName + '-' + versionCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had set a `release-signing.properties` in the project root folder. The gradle file configuration did work only after removing `release-signing.properties` file from the project root directory

Answer (score 0):

In my case i follow the steps in docs and work's, but the folder and the apk files doesn't be created. So i open the project on Android Studio and Build > Build Bundles / APKs and then it works.